# Schematic for this MCP2515-based board?

Tags: embedded, can

What is this [MCP2515](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010406) board, and is there a schematic for it?

[image]

Comment: Here's a page with the same module photograph and the schematic: http://hacktronics.co.in/home/1253-mcp2515-can-bus-module-tja1050-receivers-spi-protocol.html I found it quickly with a Google image search.

Comment: Good hit! big tnx!

Comment: Can you just put picture or link inside it, I will accpet your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic for the board is:

[image]